# Reading cell values from excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

I'm using Selenium 2 and have set up a LoginTest.java file that reads from a data driven excel file. I read in username and password and run it on a login page. It actually runs fine. The data looks like the following:

user1 pw1
user2 pw2
user3 pw3
user4 pw4

The problem is this: if I modify the excel file and change the number of arguments to something like this:

user1 pw1
user2 pw2

and run the same script, the `ReadExcel` class file returns an error msg:

> "There is no support for this type of cell".

What is happening I think, is that rows 3 and 4 *used* to contain data in their cells (user3 pw3 and user4 pw4) and now they don't...so there is something different about those previously used cells that my `ExcelRead()` class isn't catching to ignore. I'll bet the cell is now 'null' where it previously wasn't or vice versa. Something is different about the cells which previously held data vs cells that have never held data.

(I found `ExcelRead` on the internet and am using it. I didn't create it from scratch myself. It seems to work fine reading xcel files except for this one 'issue').

Thanks for any help.

```java
public class ExcelRead {
    public Object[][] main( String[] args) throws Exception{        
    File excel = new File(args[0]);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet(args[1]);

    int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
    int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
        HSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
            for (int j = 0 ; j < colNum ; j++) {
                HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                String value = cellToString(cell);
                data[i][j] = value ;
                //System.out.println("the value is " + value);
            }
        }
    return data;
    }

public static String cellToString(HSSFCell cell) {  
    int type;
    Object result;
    type = cell.getCellType();

    switch (type) {

        case 0: // numeric value in Excel
            result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
            break;
        case 1: // String Value in Excel 
            result = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
        default:  
            throw new RuntimeException("There is no support for this type of cell");                        
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have downloaded uses the Java Apache POI library to read the excel file. If you go through the code, you will see that the `cellToString()` method does not handle all types of cell types - it looks for only numeric and string cells, and throws the exception you see otherwise.

Once you removed the cell values from the rows, the cell values are now blank and you get a cell type of `CELL_TYPE_BLANK`.

You need to extend the `switch` statement in the `cellToString()` method to handle other cell types such as `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`, `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN` etc.

Refer to the [Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) on the `Cell` interface to see what  the different cell types are and how to handle each.

```
public static String cellToString(HSSFCell cell) {  
    int type;
    Object result;
    type = cell.getCellType();

    switch (type) {

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: // numeric value in Excel
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: // precomputed value based on formula
            result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: // String Value in Excel 
            result = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            result = "";
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: //boolean value 
            result: cell.getBooleanCellValue();
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
        default:  
            throw new RuntimeException("There is no support for this type of cell");                        
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that now, thank you. I added to the switch statement to check for blank but the for loop returns blank, however, what I'd like to have happen is when I delete data in a row that the row not be returned at all. I guess I don't understand how the number of rows is determined by the POI class. In my example, I have deleted rows 3 and 4 yet the ExcelRead method is still returning 4 rows (2 with data and 2 with blanks).

Comment: What you have is blank rows with blank cells. If you just want to get rid of that, delete the rows by right clicking on the row header on the left of the rows, and then clicking Delete from the context menu. This will leave you with only  the rows with data.

Comment: I get that but I wanted to know what the difference in a cell is between deleted cell data vs a cell that has never had data in it?

Comment: I wonder how int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1 ; knows how many rows there are of data? If I delete cell data it still thinks there is data in that row.

Comment: If you save the excel sheet as a .csv file you will see that it also has blank lines at the end - Excel maintains that internally and it is not an issue with your code or the Apache library.

Comment: Blank/empty is also a value and is different from null - if you delete cell content it is marked as `CELL_TYPE_BLANK`.

Comment: I hate to keep asking questions but...yes I deleted the rows and then just the top 2 rows are 'seen' by getLastRowNum(). So that means getLastRowNum() must be 'seeing' those blank rows. Well, I still have the blank cell problem if I have 4 cells of data in a row and delete the 3rd and 4th cell. I was hoping to be able to just re-use the excel file and add and delete data as needed. Doesn't sound like an easy solution to modify the ExcelRead class to detect a blank cell and then just stop the loop and move to the next row. I had added a check for "" in the cell loop but it still cont to loop

Comment: So I think that the code String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum] ; sets the outer and inner for loops. Is there a way to declare an array without knowing how big it is ahead of time? That way the loop can build the array as it goes and ignore blank cells. I looked at java arrays but didn't see how to do this with a [][] array.

Comment: You need ArrayList<String, String>.

Comment: There are several cases you will have to handle - complete row with empty cells, single/multiple cell empty on same row in between other cells etc. You should keep the logic of `ExcelRead` to read the excel file as is and then perform cleanup on the extracted [][] array. If you have trouble doing this, post a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Read Data from Excel using Java you need below jars. Download it from [this link](https://app.box.com/s/68dk6y71kmxj8jjzvojd9pqvbkvo40s6)

```
poi-4.1.0.jar 
poi-ooxml-4.1.0.jar
xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar 
ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar 
commons-compress-1.18.jar
xlsx-streamer-2.1.0.jar
```

To Read Excel file place it in downloads or user desired location. Below program Uses following [Excel file](https://app.box.com/s/gu4f8m19q8wnf7m8xsecaxh9bzhhvpbt).

Excel file may contains different types of CellTypes. While you read the columns data you need to mention mostly available CellTypes which is supported by **Apache POI**.

I refer following cases `BOOLEAN, STRING, NUMERIC, FORMULA, BLANK, _NONE, ERROR,` and if none of the case supports it goes to `default` in `getCellValueAsString` method.

```
package com.java.file.excel;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader;

/**
 * 
 * @author udaykiran p
 *
 */
public class ReadExcelFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\udaykiranp\\Downloads\\Users.xlsx");// Read Excel file from this location
            if (inputStream != null) {
                Workbook wb = StreamingReader.builder().rowCacheSize(100) // number of rows to keep in memory (default to 10)
                        .bufferSize(4096) // buffer size is to use when reading InputStream to file (defaults to 1024)
                        .open(inputStream);
                Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);//reading first sheet. You can pass argument as well.
                System.out.println("Excel Reading - Number Of Sheets: "+ wb.getNumberOfSheets() +", Active Sheet: "+ sheet.getSheetName());
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
                int rowCount = 0;
                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = iterator.next();
                    rowCount = row.getRowNum();
                    rowCount++;
                    int columnNum = 0;
                    String key = null, value = null;
                    for(Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); cellIterator.hasNext();) {
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                        columnNum = cell.getColumnIndex();
                        String cellData = getCellValueAsString(cell);
                        System.out.println("RowNumber: "+ rowCount +", CellData: "+ cellData +", CellNumber: "+ columnNum);
                        //Reading data from Excel upto 6 rows only
//                      if (rowCount == 6) {
                            //rowCount == 1 Headers Section(User ID, User Name)
                            if (rowCount > 1) {
                                if (columnNum == 0) {
                                    key = cellData;//User ID
                                }
                                if (columnNum == 1) {
                                    value = cellData;//User Name
                                }
                            }
//                      }
                    }
                    if (key != null && value != null) {
                        map.put(key, value);
                    }
                }
                String userID = "1";
                System.out.println("User ID: "+ userID +", User Name: "+ map.get("1"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getCellValueAsString(Cell cell) {
        String cellValue = null;
        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
        case BOOLEAN:
            cellValue = String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case STRING:
            cellValue = String.valueOf(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
            break;
        case NUMERIC:
            Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
            if (value != null) {
                String valueAsStr = value.toString();
                int indexOf = valueAsStr.indexOf(".");
                if (indexOf > 0) {
                    cellValue = valueAsStr.substring(0, indexOf);//decimal numbers truncated
                } else {
                    cellValue = value.toString();
                }
            }
            break;
        case FORMULA:
            //if the cell contains formula, this case will be executed.
            cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
        case BLANK:
            cellValue = "";
            break;
        case _NONE:
            cellValue = "";
            break;
        case ERROR:
            throw new RuntimeException("There is no support for this type of cell");
        default:
            cellValue = "";
        }
        return cellValue;
    }
}
```

**OutPut:**

```
DEBUG [main] (StreamingWorkbookReader.java:89) - Created temp file 

[C:\Users\UDAY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-6803178981463652112.xlsx]
Excel Reading - Number Of Sheets: 1, Active Sheet: Sheet1
RowNumber: 1, CellData: User ID, CellNumber: 0
RowNumber: 1, CellData: User Name, CellNumber: 1
RowNumber: 2, CellData: 1, CellNumber: 0
RowNumber: 2, CellData: Steve Jobs, CellNumber: 1
RowNumber: 3, CellData: 2, CellNumber: 0
RowNumber: 3, CellData: Bill Gates, CellNumber: 1
RowNumber: 4, CellData: 3, CellNumber: 0
RowNumber: 4, CellData: Sergey Brin, CellNumber: 1
RowNumber: 5, CellData: 4, CellNumber: 0
RowNumber: 5, CellData: Fritz Sennheiser, CellNumber: 1
RowNumber: 6, CellData: 5, CellNumber: 0
RowNumber: 6, CellData: Thomas Olsen, CellNumber: 1
User ID: 1, User Name: Steve Jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this.

```
case 3: break;
```

In fact you need to check for empty Cell Type (`HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`).

Also what you can do in case you find an empty cell, is stopping the `for` loop with `i=rowNum`.

There are more than two types of cell . The `getCellType()` method can return these integers:

```
Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING, Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA, Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK, Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN, Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR
```

**Edited:**

As per the observation of ***Faiz***, this will get an exception as `Object result` is not initialized and unassigned. Instead, write `case 3: return "";` it will return an empty string when a blank cell is found. Anyway, your algorithm is not the most efficient. Instead of searching through a pre-defined large area, you should search the cells until you find empty cells (if there is no empty row in your sheet). You should be able to use ArrayList instead of Array, and thus completely avoiding to process empty string during the password checking process.

Comment: The `return result.toString();` will throw an error as `result` has not been assigned a value in this case. you should assign a value to `result`.

Comment: My output is now this:

PASSED: LoginTest("a", "b", null, null)
PASSED: LoginTest("c", "d", null, null)
PASSED: LoginTest(null, null, null, null)
PASSED: LoginTest(null, null, null, null)

My excel data is:
a b
c d

So what I am expecting to see in output is:
PASSED: LoginTest("a", "b")
PASSED: LoginTest("c", "d")

I added a value check for blank string ("")

for ( int j = 0 ; j < colNum ; j++) {
 HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j) ;
 String value = cellToString(cell);
 if (value == ""){
  break;
 }
 else{
 data[i][j] = value ;
 }
}

Comment: >you should search the cells until you find empty cells.

I did add a value == "" check which I thought would stop the row processing but apparently it didn't. I'm fairly new to Java programming. I guess I don't know how or understand how to stop the method call when it finds a blank cell.

Comment: for ( int j = 0 ; j < colNum ; j++) {
     HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j) ;
     String value = cellToString(cell);
     if (value == ""){
      break;
     }
     else{
     data[i][j] = value ;
     }

Comment: To evaluate String value, you should use the equals() method and not the comparator =="". So, write if (value.equals(""){ break; } else{ data[i][j] = value ; } instead, but this will leave you with null values in some part of the String array (data) that you need to catch during the password checking process, finally, this will not work if you have an empty row between two rows containing strings (I'm not sure about your requirements).

Comment: Thank you. I could use a dynamic List<String> to capture only cells with data but is there such a thing as a double array List<String> like String[][]? How would I handle rows with 2 cols of data or 4 cols of data using a List<String>?

Comment: ArrayList<String, String>